# Request timeout for icmp_seq

Tags: terminal, timeout, ping, icmp

Using `sudo ping -f (URL)` on a Mac gives the message:

> Request timeout for icmp_seq as a reply.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I was getting the exact same thing when trying to ping my Mac from my iPhone that were on the same Airport Extreme wifi network. My firewall on my Mac was turned off. I ended up doing a reboot of the Airport Extreme and it all started working.

Answer (score 18):

The reply means the target host is unreachable which is not an error and can happen using a plain 'ping' as well.
Now, using the -f(lood) option, some firewalls or hosts can believe it's a DoS attack and drop the icmp packets silently.

Do you really need this -f option ? It can overflow the network and should be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: If your network settings were wrong, you would have other problems. Now, some hosts don't reply to icmp at all (for security reasons). Try a simple 'ping URL' to see what happens. There is no difference between ping and ping -f packets, only the emission rate. If the plain ping don't work, the ping -f will certainly not. You can try a port scan as well.

Comment: When I tried ping -f 54.206.125.84, it shows `Operation not permitted`

Comment: Try 'sudo ping -f 54.206.125.84' as the OP does. Ping is a restricted command.